# Crear un modulo que solo se pueda modificar en el panel de admin de Django

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de crear un modulo que desde el panel de adminstracion tenga un solo registro y este sea editable.
El caso es que puedo crear el modulo y verlo en el panel pero siempre puedo añadir mas de 1 registro..

Por si acaso, dejo imagenes para explicar un poco mejor lo que busco.

*Lo que tengo ahora*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Lo que busco***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Un saludo.

Comment: No es objetivo de un modelo tener un único objeto de ese tipo por lo que parece complejo lo que pides. ¿Por qué es importante que no se pueda añadir más objetos de este tipo? ¿Por qué tiene que estar en la administración?

Comment: Este modulo va a controlar un limite de elementos en un estado, por lo tanto, no puedo dejar que se añadan mas de un limite. Y debe estar en el panel de administracion porque asi lo pide el cliente...

Comment: Y entiendo que además el cliente quiere que se pueda modificar desde la administración y no desde, por ejemplo, una vista que tú pudieras crear. Porque parece que se podría solucionar con una vista que escribiera el valor a un fichero (p.e. limite.py) que a su vez sería la referencia para uno o varios campos en tus modelos. ¿Podría tu cliente aceptar esta solución?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Sokkian, el cliente, efectivamente quiere que solo se pueda modificar desde la administracion, y que ademas, solo pueda hacerlo el usuario con determinados permisos.... ¿Se te ocurre algo?

Comment: Una vista específica con restricción de acceso utilizando los controles que a tal efecto tiene Django (restricción a usuarios logeados y con permiso X para eso) No sería difícil añadir un campo extra para poder marcar los usuarios con ese permiso y que sea solo el superadmin quien pudiera modificarlo. Se puede poner el enlace en la admin ;)